# Get Array values using a class in c#

Tags: c#

i have declared 2 string values eg: ChName1, ChName2 and 2 int values eg: Delay1, Delay2 in the settings.

i would like to implement an array in class so life will be more easier. can somebody correct my code with necessary explanations

```
public class GetDefaultValues
    {
        public string Name[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName1;
                    case 1:
                        return Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName2;
                    default:
                        return "Not Implemented";
                }
            }

            set
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName1 = value;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        {
                            Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName2 = value;
                            break;
                        }
                }

                Name.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }

        public int Value[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return Name.Properties.Settings.Default.Delay1;
                    case 1:
                        return Name.Properties.Settings.Default.Delay2;
                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
            }

            set
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            Name.Properties.Settings.Default.Delay1 = value;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        {
                            Name.Properties.Settings.Default.Delay2 = value;
                            break;
                        }
                }

                Name.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

then in my main code i could do like this

```
GetDefaultValues Vlues = new GetDefaultValues();
Vlues.Name[0] = "SomeName";
string SomeString = Vlues.Name[1];

Vlues.Value[0] = 125;
int SomeInt = Vlues.Value[1];
```

this code is generating errors in my code.

> Error 2 Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank
>   specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size
>   buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type

will be happy if i could know why??
please help!!

Comment: *this code is generating errors in my code* Which errors?
You realy should use methods instead of properties for this...

Comment: Error 2 Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type

Comment: In addition to the error you should also say where the error happened. I am confident that you were told exactly which line the problem was on so you should not leave us guessing....

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend not to use properties for this because properties should not have that logic. You should use methods instead.

This could be look like this for example (just added the name as a sample).

```
public class GetDefaultValues
{
    public bool SetName(int i, string value)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName1 = value;
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName2 = value;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                return false;
        }

        Name.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        return true;
    }

    public string GetName(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                return Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName1;
            case 1:
                return Name.Properties.Settings.Default.ChName2;
            default:
                return "Not Implemented";
        }
    }
}
```

This would be called like this

```
GetDefaultValues Vlues = new GetDefaultValues();
bool success = Vlues.SetName(0, "SomeName");
string SomeString = Vlues.Name(1);
```

You can make the `SetName` method a `void` method if you don't want to have the info if it worked or not.

Comment: thanks for reply. this is how i am currently implementing. but would like to know if properties could be used some how??

Comment: @joshinjoy As far as I know there is no way doing it with properties. And if there is one I would still recommend not putting this much logic in a property.